# How to check if permissions for /usr/local, /usr/local/bin, /usr/share/man/man1 have been altered, and how to restore them?

Tags: terminal, catalina, bash, permission

Following this answer

https://superuser.com/a/1025007/642458

I tried to install `tree` from source. Running `make install` the first time, I got this output:

```
...$ make install
install -d /usr/local/bin
install: chmod 755 /usr/local/bin: Operation not permitted
install -d /usr/share/man/man1
install: chmod 755 /usr/share/man/man1: Read-only file system
if [ -e tree ]; then \
        install tree /usr/local/bin/tree; \
    fi
install: /usr/local/bin/tree: Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

Since the answer mentions using `sudo`, I ran `sudo make install`, which worked for what it concerns moving the `tree` binary to `/usr/local/bin`, but not for what it concerns adding the `man` pages:

```
install -d /usr/local/bin
install -d /usr/share/man/man1
install: chmod 755 /usr/share/man/man1: Read-only file system
if [ -e tree ]; then \
        install tree /usr/local/bin/tree; \
    fi
install doc/tree.1 /usr/share/man/man1/tree.1
install: /usr/share/man/man1/tree.1: Read-only file system
make: *** [install] Error 71
```

However, I'm now afraid that I changed the permissions for my system folders! At least this seems to be the case for `/usr/local/bin` (look at the time and date of `.`):

```
...$ ls -alt /usr/local/bin
total 1912
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root           wheel  109008 Dec  8 15:11 tree
drwxr-xr-x  44 root           wheel    1408 Dec  8 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root           wheel     736 Sep 26 10:12 ..
.
.
```

How can I check if the permissions to my system folders have been altered, and how can I restore them? Do I need to check only `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/share/man/man1`, or should I check other folders too? Here is the `Makefile`, in case you want to look at it:

```
# $Copyright: $
# Copyright (c) 1996 - 2018 by Steve Baker
# All Rights reserved
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA

prefix = /usr

CC=gcc

VERSION=1.8.0
TREE_DEST=tree
BINDIR=${prefix}/bin
MAN=tree.1
MANDIR=${prefix}/man/man1
OBJS=tree.o unix.o html.o xml.o json.o hash.o color.o file.o

# Uncomment options below for your particular OS:

# Linux defaults:
#CFLAGS=-ggdb -pedantic -Wall -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
#CFLAGS=-O4 -Wall  -DLINUX -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
#LDFLAGS=-s

# Uncomment for FreeBSD:
#CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer
#LDFLAGS=-s
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for OpenBSD:
#TREE_DEST=colortree
#MAN=colortree.1
#CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer
#LDFLAGS=-s
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for Solaris:
#CC=cc
#CFLAGS=-xO0 -v
#LDFLAGS=
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o
#MANDIR=${prefix}/share/man/man1

# Uncomment for Cygwin:
#CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN
#LDFLAGS=-s
#TREE_DEST=tree.exe
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for OS X:
# It is not allowed to install to /usr/bin on OS X any longer (SIP):
prefix = /usr/local
CC=cc
CFLAGS=-O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -no-cpp-precomp
LDFLAGS=
MANDIR=/usr/share/man/man1
OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for HP/UX:
#CC=cc
#CFLAGS=-O2 -DAportable -Wall
#LDFLAGS=
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for OS/2:
#CFLAGS=-02 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -Zomf -Zsmall-conv
#LDFLAGS=-s -Zomf -Zsmall-conv
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# Uncomment for HP NonStop:
#prefix = /opt
#CC=c89
#CFLAGS=-Wextensions -WIEEE_float -g -Wnowarn=1506 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1 \
#    -Wallow_cplusplus_comments
#LDFLAGS=
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

# AIX
#CC=cc_r -q64
#LD=ld -d64
#LDFLAGS=-lc
#OBJS+=strverscmp.o

#------------------------------------------------------------

all:    tree

tree:   $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TREE_DEST) $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): %.o:   %.c tree.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    if [ -x $(TREE_DEST) ]; then rm $(TREE_DEST); fi
    if [ -f tree.o ]; then rm *.o; fi
    rm -f *~

install: tree
    install -d $(BINDIR)
    install -d $(MANDIR)
    if [ -e $(TREE_DEST) ]; then \
        install $(TREE_DEST) $(BINDIR)/$(TREE_DEST); \
    fi
    install doc/$(MAN) $(MANDIR)/$(MAN)

distclean:
    if [ -f tree.o ]; then rm *.o; fi
    rm -f *~
    

dist:   distclean
    tar zcf ../tree-$(VERSION).tgz -C .. `cat .tarball`
```

**EDIT**: my OS is MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your comment. I'm running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Catalina has SIP, so unless you disabled that you can't accidentally change the permissions on stuff outside /usr/local. That's why you got `chmod 755 /usr/share/man/man1: Read-only file system` errors.

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug in the makefile. The directory for the man files is hard coded incorrectly.

The top is correct

```
BINDIR=${prefix}/bin
MAN=tree.1
MANDIR=${prefix}/man/man1
```

Unfortunately the OSX bit hard codes MANDIR you need to edit that line to the one above.

I would note this is not a good makefile - as things like MANDIR and BINDIR are set in several places. These should be set at the end of the configuration and the OSX bit just sets prefix and the compiler options (or perhaps better all installs should be with PREFIX=/usr/local for all Unix OS).

Now reading the details of the link it is worse - the original author of the source code got it correct but the hacks to make it build are wrong. The correct way is in a comment in the answer

> Well, this technically works. But it’s invasive. So you could probably run ./configure --prefix=/usr/local before running make and make install and it would achieve the same results.

I have not tried this so can't be certain it works - I would use Macports (or Homebrew) where someone else has already done the hard work of portting the build to macOS and also they provide a binary so you don't even need to compile it yourself. Macports also keeps the directory permissions as they should be for Unix (Homebrew does require some messing around with directory permissions but just /usr/local )

As for chnages to the file system re permissions etc. Thje security is working and you made no chnages. macOS stopped the only commands that change permissions chmod

To check run `ls -ld directory` for any directory you might be worried about.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, I'm mostly worried about the folder permissions having changed. How do I check which system folders had their permission changed, and how do I restore them?

Comment: There is nothing in what you have shown to say that there have been any chnages. The script could not write to /usr/man/man1 and that was reported correctly